# 'heroku run python manage.py migrate' fails with an error 'Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process'

Tags: python, django, heroku

i have tried 'heroku run python manage.py migrate' and get " Timeout awaiting dyno, see https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#timeout-awaiting-process" error.

heroku logs

```
 2015-05-06T05:42:05.881706+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `manage.py db:migrate` by navajyothms1989@gmail.com
```

2015-05-06T05:42:22.537124+00:00 heroku[run.9766]: Awaiting client
2015-05-06T05:42:22.789430+00:00 heroku[run.9766]: State changed from starting to up
2015-05-06T05:42:52.552578+00:00 heroku[run.9766]: Error R13 (Attach error) -> Failed to attach to process
2015-05-06T05:42:53.293185+00:00 heroku[run.9766]: Process exited with status 128
2015-05-06T05:42:53.307222+00:00 heroku[run.9766]: State changed from up to complete

What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same thing happened to me. But it was solved by connecting to my mobile internet. My ISP was blocking most of the ports it seems and heroku run command takes random ports.